# Compare database table with value of option select box php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to sort table data using a select option box which also gets options from the database. So basically If i select option Chairman, it is supposed to populate the table with candidates vying for chairman position. However I am running into a wall because the sql syntax seems incorrect. Please help

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['sort'])) {
            $sql1=" SELECT tbpositions.position_id, tbcandidates.candidate_name, tbcandidates.candidate_position FROM tbpositions 
            INNER JOIN tbcandidates ON
            tbpositions.position_id=tbcandidates.position_id WHERE ($row['position_name']==$_POST[$position_name])";


            $result =   mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
            $count  =   mysqli_num_rows($result);
        }
?>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? also there is an SQL injection exploit in your code, please make sure you escape all user input before running queries.

Comment: What exactly is the problem, which let you think, the sql statement is wrong?

Comment: The statement returns the entire table, but i want it to sort the tabld data depending on selection from option box

Comment: Correct to only one equality sign in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The description and the code are very... confusing. You have three values: `$_POST['sort']`, `$row['position_name']`, `$_POST[$position_name]`. And you speak of some kind of sorting. Though your sql statement has nothing regarding sorting in it. Also, you speak about "_populate the table_". Which table? Could you please reedit your question to be a bit clearer?

Comment: And what is/should be `$row['position_name']` in there?